# Google API level Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, api

I would like to change Google API level for my app project in Eclipse.  I have seen numerous responses to this question on other forums that state to Right-Click on Project, select Android and edit the API level.  However in my version of Eclipse (Classic) the Target API level can not be edited in this way. The box can not be edited.

I have tried the other common method of updating the manifest file but this doesnt seem to work without completing the required step mentioned above.

Any solutions would be very welcome.

Comment: have you downloaded other versions of android in your Android SDK Manager?

Comment: No (face palm).  I assume I do this and there will be other options for me to select from.  I will try now.

Comment: I believe that when someone with more experience helps a newbie, a star is born in the sky.  Thank you Dyna.

Comment: ahahah you are welcome newbie ;) I 'll post it as an answer so you can give me precious points!!

Comment: one question, and why you want to update the G Api ?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Android SDK Manager and download the API of the version that you wanna work on .
Now you can follow the other steps.